# Is amazon has any meta tag that with og:image,or any other meta tag for sharing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, share

Link: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BJM1MXG5/ref=sspa_dk_rhf_detail_pt_sub_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9yaGZfZGV0YWlsp13NParams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BJM1MXG5)

I open the console,and search meta tag,but i could not find meta tag with og:image.And when i share  the site to fb,or twitter,the share card could show image,like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiiV6.png)

so what i can do for this.

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="xxxxxx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="HELLO WORLD" />
<meta property="og:description" content="yyyyyyyyyy" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.ltwebstatic.com/images3_pi/2023/05/16/168422358614d90a8cb6e2f21f4f440aa22588864a.png" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

now i firstly add these tag on my site,and then share my site,i can see image on the share card.
any other methods could do it？

Comment: Seems the [og:image](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fdp%2FB0BJM1MXG5) is definitely set

Comment: I can't find it either

Comment: what's with the `reactjs` AND `vue.js` tag spam?